# Basic questions on matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, image-processing

I'd like to implemente a matrix multiplication among three matrices sized at `1*256`, `256*256` and `256*1`. But I'm stucked at matrices type setting and multiplication.
Currently my code is like

```
Inner[Times, Table[N[XSub[10, r]], {1}, {r, 1, 256}], MatrixForm[A], Table[N[YSub[10, s]], {s, 1, 256}, {1}]]
```

where A sized at 256*256.
The result I expected is like
[image]

Two Questions:

1. I'm confused at creating the 1D matrix by `Table[]` , `List[]` or something else. My code above can create the Matrices I want, but it dosen't work on Matrix multiplication I wanted.
2. I've tried to combine `.` and `*` to reach expected result on small-size matrices. but it dosen't work on matrices I created above.

Comment: I'm confused... if you multiply matrices of sizes 1x256, 256x256, 256x1 then the answer is a scalar, not a matrix.

Comment: `MatrixForm` is for display only. It kills a computation when it appears inside one.

Comment: One should know that a vector has not to be specified as column or row in WL.

Comment: Hi @bills, a scalar and a 1-by-1 matrix are different, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matrix operations, especially with vectors, are a bit confusing in Mathematica.

```
ClearAll[v1, v2, a, b, c, x, y, z];
v1 = {a, b, c}; m = Partition[Range[9], 3]; v2 = {x, y, z};
```

Use MatrixForm to display the expressions nicely. They are still just lists.

```
Map[MatrixForm, {v1, m, v2}];
```

Then the inner product or Dot gives a scalar as Bill said (1x3, 3x3, 3x1)

```
v1.m.v2

    (a + 4 b + 7 c) x + (2 a + 5 b + 8 c) y + (3 a + 6 b + 9 c) z
```

What you might mean is a "3BY1 1BY3" matrix multiplication

```
z1 = KroneckerProduct[v1, v2]

    {{a x, a y, a z}, {b x, b y, b z}, {c x, c y, c z}}
```

This next operation (with *) is not really a normal kind of matrix or tensor operation, so check your mathematics and your meaning, but you can do it.

```
z2 = z1 * m

    {{a x, 2 a y, 3 a z}, {4 b x, 5 b y, 6 b z}, {7 c x, 8 c y, 9 c z}}
```

Gives what you seek.  Realize there are three kinds of operation used here: Dot/Inner, KroneckerProduct (see also TensorProduct and Outer), and Times.

Hope this helps.

(All--I'll take any kind of guidance or link in the chat room on how to better format answers and show 2D output in StackExchange.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination, it answered my question. But my 256*256 size matrix still dose not work. Reason might be that matrix cannot be multiplied here. For example, in your answer, `m` is a list. But my matrix here is not list type. And the computation result is just putting them together. How can I solve it?

Comment: Uh, I got it. I just deleted the `MatrixForm` from initial input. Thanks for all response!

Comment: Yep. You rarely (very rarely) want to mix Set(=) or SetDelayed(:=) with MatrixForm or similar commands. I've been burned so many times with  a = (SOME OPERATION) // MatrixForm.

Comment: (+1) Very nice! Also `Outer[Times, v1,v2] m1` and (it would seem) `(TensorProduct[v1,v2] m1)==(KroneckerProduct[v1,v2] m1)==Inner[Times, (v1 m1), v2, List]==(Outer[Times, v1,v2] m1)` (with v1,v2 and m1 defined in my own effort).

Comment: @PaulCommentary use the grave key ` to type commands, e.g. "grave"Map"grave" -> `Map`

Answer (score 1):

```
Inner[Times, (v1 m1), v2, List]
```

> {{a x, 2 a y, 3 a z}, {4 b x, 5 b y, 6 b z}, {7 c x, 8 c y, 9 c z}}

Alternatively:

```
List@@@((m1 v1).v2)
```

or

```
Outer[Times, v1,v2] m1
```

---

**Data**

```
Clear[a,b,c];
v1= {a,b,c}
m1= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
v2={x,y,z};
```

---

**Comparison**

Combining with the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225283/106) of [PaulCommentary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/54458/paulcommentary):

```
Inner[Times,(m1 v1), v2, List]==
List@@@((m1 v1).v2)==
(Outer[Times, v1,v2] m1)==
(TensorProduct[v1,v2] m1)==
(KroneckerProduct[v1,v2] m1)
```

> True